# Are references to Annotations constant?

Tags: java, annotations

if I call `getAnnotation()` on the same `Field` with the same `Class<? extends Annotation>` as parameter, will the result always be the same instance of the annotation's `class`?

I know that `Annotations` are cached, but is there something that might clear the cache/something that might make it risky to rely on this instance?

Comment: Normally this is true, but all bets are off if you have multiple classloaders.

Comment: @JimGarrison That would be a different `Field` even if it has the same name/class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you look at the source code for `getAnnotation` it reads as follows:

```
public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass) {
    if (annotationClass == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    return (T) declaredAnnotations().get(annotationClass);
}
```

the `declaredAnnotations` method is coded like:

```
private synchronized  Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> declaredAnnotations() {
    if (declaredAnnotations == null) {
        declaredAnnotations = AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(
            annotations, sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().
            getConstantPool(getDeclaringClass()),
            getDeclaringClass());
    }
    return declaredAnnotations;
}
```

And the `declaredAnnotations` field is a map:

```
private transient Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> declaredAnnotations;
```

In summary, the annotations are stored in the map, and the same ones are returned once they have been retrieved.